# Mutex Protect Macro

Tags: c++, macros, mutex

This is one of my first posts on this community, so please bear with me.

Is there a way to mutex protect a macro, in the macro itself.

For example,

```
#define FUNCTION_ \
doSomething()
```

Basically, I'm looking to do something like this

```
#define FUNCTION_ \
mutex.lock \
doSomething() \
mutex.unlock
```

For further information, the macros are all declared within a header file, by themselves ( no namespace or class), which handles calls to an API. We are utilizing C++. This header file is utilized by multiple projects therefore an overhaul of the macro itself is out of the question. For more detail on the Macro, it wraps calls to log4CXX.log4CXX is threadsafe; however, two threads utilizing this macro, who make a write call at the same time is not thread safe. Helgrind complains when running Valgrind about that. Mutex protecting the macro in the code fixes the problem, but instead of mutex protection every single call, have the macro protect its own call.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If you're using C++ I would suggest something other than a macro and use lock guards.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You can try this yourself and see, if it works. Just add the missing parenthesis and you're done.

Comment: We use C++. The project uses a macro to wrap API calls for log4CXX. log4CXX is threadsafe; however, two threads utilizing this macro, who make a write call at the same time is not thread safe. Helgrind complains when running Valgrind about that. Mutex protecting the macro in the code fixes the problem, but instead of mutex protection every single call, have the macro protect its own call.

Comment: It's simple to state to use something other than a macro and use lock guards, that is ideal; however, the code affects multiple projects and that would require too many changes.

Comment: @HunterLee please [edit] your question and put clarifications _there_.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, thanks - I did just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the code. Just cover it up.
This should do:

```
#define FUNCTION_ \
do { \
    mutex.lock() \
    doSomething() \
    mutex.unlock() \
} while(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question when it comes to the mutex. This file is header with no namespace or class. Declaring a mutex results in a complaint during compilation of multiple definitions existing. Bear in mind, this mutex is a wrapper of pthread_mutex_t.

Comment: @HunterLee that should be a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already this

```
#define FUNCTION_ \
doSomething()
```

and if there is really no chance to stop such macro madness, then at least dont take it one step further. If you need a lock in `doSomething()` then the easiest would be to acquire the lock in the function:

```
void doSomething() {
    mutex.lock();
    /* .... */ 
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

or if for some reason you cannot change the function then wrap it

```
#define FUNCTION_ \
doSoemthingLocked()

void doSomethingLocked() {
    mutex.lock();
    doSomething();
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

(maybe declared as inline if you need to put it in a header, and maybe passing a reference to the mutex as parameter)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem is as follows:

```
#define FUNCTION_ \
{ \
   mutex.lock(); \
   doSomething(); \
   mutex.unlock(); \
} \
```

However, for the mutex itself I have a mutex that wraps the pthread_mutex_t so in this situation I declared the mutex as:

extern Mutex mutex;

Then in a .cpp file:

```
#include <headerFile.hpp>

Mutex mutex;
```

This creates a single instance of the mutex and prevents issues with multiple instances of the same name being discovered.